# Android project not generated regurlary after import from svn in ADT eclipse

Tags: android, svn

Whenever I import an android project from `svn` the project doesn't generate properly.

So I have errors in the values files and the `R.java` is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure about that, if any errors on your res file
2. Clean your project
3. Restart your ADT

Answer (score 0):

You can **update** the whole project folder from outside but while doing a **commit** instead if committing the the whole project folder **only update the following from inside the project folder**:

- **src** folder (to update the code)
- **res** folder (to update the UIs, XMLs images, etc.)
- **AndroidManifest.xml** if anything added to it.
- **libs** folder if you have add any external libraries and JARs.
- clean and/or refresh your project after each update.

Ask your team to follow this approach because folders like **gen** etc are auto-generated by the SDK.